# Error: nothing to repeat when counting occurences in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, spyder, python-3.8

I try to count the occurences of each emoji (in the emoji library) in my dataframe.
My approach:

```
emoji_cnt = [[] for i in range(len(list(emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI.keys())))]

j = 0
for key, value in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI.items():
    emoji_cnt[j].append(key)
    j = j+1

for k in emoji_cnt: 
    s = df["Message"].str.count(k[0]).sum()
    k.append(s)
```

actually works. I tried to print the numbers out (within in the Loop) and it works. But some how the programm stops and I get the following Error:

```
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py", line 668, in _parse
    raise source.error("nothing to repeat",

error: nothing to repeat
```

I am using Spyder on Anaconda and Python 3.8.

Thank you very much guys :)

Kind regards from Vienna!

Answer (score 0):

So found a way.
I had to use thge module for regular expressions.
so:

```
import re
.
.
.
emoji_cnt = [[] for i in range(len(list(emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI.keys())))]

j = 0
for key, value in emoji.UNICODE_EMOJI.items():
    emoji_cnt[j].append(key)
    j = j+1

for k in emoji_cnt: 
    s = df["Message"].str.count(re.escape(k[0])).sum()
    k.append(s)
```

**re.escape(k[0])** will change the Emoji in k[0] into an regular expression.

:)